# Getting child attributes in Laravel 9x blades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have two components, **tab.blade.php** and **tab-content.blade.php** where `tab` must be the parent tag having one or many nested `tab-content`s.

Inside **tab.blade.php** I need to have a list of all tab-content child id attributes before calling `{{ $slot }}`.

```
<x-tab>
    <x-tab-content id="a">testA</x-tab-content>
    <x-tab-content id="b">testB</x-tab-content>
    <x-tab-content id="c">testC</x-tab-content>
</x-tab>
```

Is that possible to access child attributes in Laravel 9x blades?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you are trying?

Comment: @Coola sure. This `<x-tab` component will need to produce two HTML blocks. One of them will have a `<div>` with nav buttons and below that div, each tab-content will produce its div with the tab contents.

However, the buttons in the nav div need to point to each content ID. The nav menu can't be inside the same component as the content list... so just calling `{{ $slot }}` is not an option as the tab-content can't generate its own nav button. Does that make sense?